# java mongodb - set a field only if it is in range

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

In mongodb i have a field that must be from 0 to `MAX` (an integer final variable).
every time the value hits `MAX` it must return to 0.
to perform this i tried this (java):

```
Document document = coll.findOneAndUpdate(
    filter,
    new Document(//update
        "$inc",
        new Document("counter", 1)
     )
);
int count = (document != null) ? document.getInteger("counter") : 0;
if(count >= MAX) {
    count-= MAX;
    coll.updateOne(filter, new Document("$set", new Document("counter", count));
}
```

the only problem is that this is not synchronized, and can cause the counter to lose some counts if multiple clients access this at the same time. to make this synchronized i must test that `count` is in range from `count` to `max` before setting it, how can i achieve this?

Comment: You can put the code snippet inside synchronized block.. But it badly hits the performance.

Comment: it's not just only performance, it will not be atomic for multiple machines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform two requests : reset the counter to 0 of it is equal to MAX. Then increase the counter by one. All this using mongodb mechanism such as findAndModify, which guarantees atomicity !

Comment: a little improvement to use less requests: i can set the counter to 1 and do not send the increment.